# Comparar 2 tablas de la base de datos mediante PHP

Tags: php, mysql, submit

estoy haciendo un programa donde comparo en una base de datos (Mysql-Workbench) 2 columnas `(difficulty, difficulty_student)` de 2 tablas diferentes **(EXERCISES, ANSWERS)** en una columna `difficulty_choice` de la tabla **ANSWERS**.

Me refiero a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparo ambas tablas mediante un VARCHAR (YES or NO). Si el usuario ha cambiado la dificultad del ejercicio, la celda será ‘YES’, si no la ha cambiado, la celda será ‘NO’.

Estas son mis tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT,
    difficulty VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    difficulty_change VARCHAR(3),
    difficulty_student VARCHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);
```

Mi problema es que las líneas de la tabla ANSWERS no existen hasta que el usuario pulse **SUBMIT** en el programa. Por lo que solo he conseguido que se comparen las columnas que están en la tabla mediante los comandos que hay debajo en Mysql-Workbench.

Lo que necesito es que las columnas se comparen en `difficulty_change` cuando el usuario pulse **SUBMIT**. Me podéis ayudar a hacerlo? No lo consigo.

He conseguido que se comparen las columnas mediante los siguientes códigos pero quiero que se llamen desde el programa para que no tenga que ir a Mysql-Workbench cada vez para ejecutarlos.

```
SELECT e.difficulty, a.difficulty_student, 
case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' 
         END  as difficulty_change
FROM exercises e 
INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk;


UPDATE answers a 
INNER JOIN exercises e  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk 
set a.difficulty_change = case 
     when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' END
where e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk;
```

Este es mi php que puede que ayude:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'";
    if(isset($_POST['choice'], $_POST['choose'])){
            $choice_answer=$_POST['choice'];
            $difficulty=$_POST['choose'];
//      */$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];*/
            $query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_student, choice_answer) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$difficulty', '$choice_answer')";
            $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿@ana es cuando inserte que quieres que diga si el estudiante a cambiado de dificultad?

Comment: Si @junior, me gustaría saber si el estudiante ha cambiado la dificultad, por eso necesito comparar cuando se presione el botón Submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una subquery

```
$query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_change, difficulty_student, choice_answer) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', (SELECT IF(difficulty='$difficulty','NO','YES') FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id=$id), '$difficulty', '$choice_answer')";
```

Comment: Sustituyo mi línea de php  `$query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_student, choice_answer) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$difficulty', '$choice_answer')";` por la tuya? Es lo que dices?

Comment: si eso es lo que digo

Comment: Wow no me creo que funcione! Tan facil era? Gracias por tu ayuda. Creia que iba a ser más complicado.

Comment: Hola junior, tengo una pregunta parecida a esta que no consigo sacar en: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189475/bot%C3%B3n-radio-no-definido] ¿Me podrías ayudar?