# Botón radio no definido

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, radiobutton

Estoy trabajando en un simple programa de test. Se muestra una pregunta a la vez con 3 respuestas posibles en los botones de opción. La respuesta para cada pregunta se almacena en una tabla de una base de datos llamada SOLUCIÓN:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa obtengo el siguiente error: `Undefined variable: solution_number.` ¿Me podéis ayudar a definir la variable `solution_number` en mis botones de radio? No estoy segura de cómo hacerlo.

Aquí está mi código para los botones de radio:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "1"  /><img src="<?php echo $row["image_path_A"] ?>"/><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "2" /><img src="<?php echo $row["image_path_B"] ?>"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "3" /><img src="<?php echo $row["image_path_C"] ?>"><br>


<p2>Select difficulty level:</p2>

<form action='' method='post'>
    <select name="choose" id="choose">>
    <option value="1" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="1") { echo "selected"; } ?> >1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="2") { echo "selected"; } ?> >2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="3") { echo "selected"; } ?> >3</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="4") { echo "selected"; } ?> >4</option>
    <option value="5" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="5") { echo "selected"; } ?> >5</option>
</select>


    <input class="buttonSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <?php
    if ($next_question_id >= 0) {
    ?>
        <a href="?id=<?php echo $next_question_id; ?>&order=<?php echo $next_question_order; ?>" class="buttonNext" >Next Question</a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

</form>
```

Aquí está mi PHP: El error aparece aquí en ‘`solution_number`’. Y no está definido.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'";
    if(isset($_POST['choice'], $_POST['choose'])){
        $choice_answer=$_POST['choice'];
        $difficulty=$_POST['choose'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_change, difficulty_student, choice_answer, correct_answer)
                VALUES ('$id','$user_id', (SELECT IF(difficulty='$difficulty','NO','YES') FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id=$id), 
                        '$difficulty', '$choice_answer', 
                        (SELECT IF(solution_number='$solution_number','1','0') FROM solution WHERE exercise_id_fk=$id))";

        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    }
}
?>
```

`solution_number` es la respuesta verdadera del ejercicio, mientras que `choice_answer` es la respuesta que elige el usuario. Lo que intento hacer es compara ambas respuestas y guardarlas en una columna BOOLEANA llamada `correct_answer`.

Estas son mis **tablas de la base de datos**:

```
CREATE TABLE solution(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    solution_number INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    choice_answer INT,
   correct_answer BOOLEAN,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);
```

Y así es como comparo ambas columnas pero no consigo que aparezca la comparación cada vez que el usuario pulse submit:

```
SELECT s.solution_number, a.choice_answer, 
case when s.solution_number = a.choice_answer then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' 
         END  as correct_answer
FROM solution s 
INNER JOIN answers a  on s.exercise_id_fk=a.exercise_id_fk;


UPDATE answers a 
INNER JOIN solution s  on s.exercise_id_fk=a.exercise_id_fk 
set a.correct_answer = case 
     when s.solution_number = a.choice_answer then true else false END
where s.exercise_id_fk=a.exercise_id_fk;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
(SELECT IF(solution_number='$choice_answer','1','0') FROM solution WHERE exercise_id_fk=$id))
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ampliar un poco tu respuesta?  cuanto mejor explicas tu respuesta, más útil será para ñps demás. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar me parece que la línea donde redefines por segunda vez el inicio de la etiqueta del formulario:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
```

Está demás.

En segundo lugar el error te está diciendo exactamente lo que sucede, y es que en la línea donde defines la query, exactamente en este tramo:

```
(SELECT IF(solution_number='$solution_number','1','0') FROM solution WHERE exercise_id_fk=$id))";
```

Le estás pasando como argumento la variable `$solution_number` pero que realmente no la estás creando en ningún sitio. Me animo a pensar que lo que realmente querías poner es:

```
solution_number='$choice_answer'
```

Comment: En realidad `solution_number` es la respuesta verdadera del ejercicio, mientras que `choice_answer` es la respuesta que elige el usuario. Lo que intento hacer es compara ambas respuestas y guardarlas en una columna BOOLEANA llamada `correct_answer`. He probado tu respuesta pero no funciona como debería. Necesitas que te enseñe más código? o mi base de datos?

Comment: Entiendo. Lo que debes hacer es crear la variable `$solution_number` con la solución correcta, ya sea poniendo la respuesta directamente en la variable u obteniéndola de base de datos, depende de tus requerimientos. Y otra cosa, creo que no has de usar el operador de asignación `=` en este caso, sino el de  comparación `==` o `===`.

Comment: He añadido en la pregunta cómo guardo la respuesta en una tabla de la base de datos y como comparo ambos valores mediante `correct_answer`. Lo que pasa es que me gustaría que comparase valores al presionar `SUBMIT` y no lo está haciendo. ¿Crees que con esta información me puedes ayudar?